# How can I use Windows to create an OS X El Capitan or macOS Sierra USB flash drive installer from the disk image (.dmg) file downloaded from Apple?

Tags: macos, windows, usb, install, dmg

There are many posts on the Internet where instructions are given for creating OS X USB installers by using the [TransMac](https://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm) and other such applications on a Windows machine. Many of these posts assume one is starting with a disk image (.dmg) file made from an existing OS X USB flash drive installer.

An `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file for [OS X El Capitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan), can be downloaded from the Apple website [How to download macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683). While this file can be restored to a flash drive, the result is not a working OS X El Capitan USB installer. The same is true for the [macOS Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) file `InstallOS.dmg` file, which can be downloaded from the [same](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) Apple website.

How can I use Windows to create an OS X El Capitan or macOS Sierra USB flash drive installer from a `.dmg` file, which can be downloaded from Apple?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Note: Links to instructions for other versions of OS X/macOS can found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/460961#460961).

User [Josué Mpindi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/483752/josu%C3%A9-mpindi) posted a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453127/how-to-reinstalled-macos-sierra-from-usb-start-up-disk-made-using-transmac), where this answer was confirmed to work for macOS Sierra in a [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/659737). Note that where necessary, you would need to substitute Sierra references for El Capitan in the instructions.

> Note: A version of this answer, which uses macOS to create the USB flash drive OS X El Capitan installer, can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379603/how-do-i-create-el-capitan-installer-on-a-catalina-or-post-el-capitan-installe/389830#389830).

Using Windows to create an USB flash drive OS X El Capitan installer requires third party software beyond just TransMac. The steps below outline one possible method for creating an USB flash drive OS X El Capitan installer using Windows and other free third party tools.

> Note: These instructions will not work for Yosemite. For the correct Yosemite instructions, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448811/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-yosemite-usb-flash-drive-installer-from/448812#448812).

1. Use Microsoft Edge (or some other web browser) to download the following installers to your Downloads folder. The file names are current as of September 22, 2022. If both 32 bit and 64 bit versions are available, the 64 bit version is given in the table.

   | Product | Use | Installer | Type |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | [El Capitan 10.11](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683#browser)<sup>†</sup> | Free for use on Mac computers | `InstallMacOSX.dmg` | Mac Disk Image |
   | [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org) | Free | `7z2201-x64.exe` | Application |
   | [TransMac](https://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm) | 15 day free trial | `tmsetup.zip` | Compressed (zipped) Folder |
   | [Paragon Partition Manager Community Edition 64bit](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/pm-express/) | Free for personal and home use | `Paragon-1081-FRU_WinInstallDemo_x64_17.9.1_000.exe` | Application |

   <sup>†</sup><sub>If you get the message “InstallMacOSX.dmg can't be download securely”, then select “Keep”, as shown below.</sub>

   [image]
2. Install all downloads except [“El Capitan 10.11”](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp728?locale=en_US). If you wish, the installed downloads can be uninstalled from the Windows Control Panel after use.
3. Use a 7-Zip File Manager application window to extract the `OS X Install ESD` folder and the `InstallAssistant.icns` file to your Downloads folder. From a File Explorer window, start by navigating to your Downloads folder. In this window, right click on the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` Mac disk image file, then select "7-Zip" > "Open archive". This should open a 7-Zip File Manager application window. In this window, right click on each file or folder in the order given in the table below, then select the corresponding action. When finished, close the 7-Zip File Manager application window.

   | File or Folder | Action | Type | Comment |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | `Install OS X` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `InstallMacOSX.pkg` | Open Inside * | Package File |  |
   | `InstallMacOSX.pkg` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `InstallESD.dmg` | Open | Mac Disk Image File |  |
   | `OS X Install ESD` | Copy To… | Folder | See footnote ‡ |
   | `OS X Install ESD` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `BaseSystem.dmg` | Open | Mac Disk Image File |  |
   | `OS X Base System` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `Install OS X El Capitan.app` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `Contents` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `Resources` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `InstallAssistant.icns` | Copy To… | Apple Icon Image File | See footnote ‡ |

   <sup>‡</sup><sub>The destination should be your Downloads folder. If this Downloads folder exists on a volume that is not NTFS formatted, then see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/449664#449664).</sub>
4. Insert a 16 GB or larger flash drive into an USB port. If prompted, you do  not need to initialize the flash drive.
5. Open the TransMac application with Administrator privileges. (In other words, right click on the TransMac icon, then choose "Run as administrator" or "More" >  "Run as administrator".) In the TranMac application window, take the following actions.

   - Select "Tools" > "Settings" from the pulldown menu. In the "General" tab of the "Settings" popup, select the same copy options as shown below.

     [image: TransMac General Settings]

     Select `OK` when finished.
   - Right click on the USB flash drive icon in the treeview pane, then select "Restore with Disk Image". In the "Restore Disk Image to Drive" popup , choose to "Open" the `OS X Install ESD\BaseSystem.dmg` Mac disk image file in your Downloads folder as the Disk Image to restore, then select the `OK` button. Next, select `Yes` in the "Last Warning!" popup.
6. Open the Paragon Partition Manager 17 CE application. Select to resize the partition with the Apple HFS volume on the USB flash drive to maximum size, as shown below. Next, select the "Change now" button. When finished, select the "Close" button.

   [image]

   Next, select to change the volume label on this Apple HFS volume from "OS X Base System" to "Install El Capitan", as shown below. Next, select the "Change now" button. When finished, select the "Close" button.

   [image]

   When finished, close the Paragon Partition Manager 17 CE application window.
7. In the existing TranMac window, take the following actions.

   - Select "Tools" > "Refresh Drive List" from the pulldown menu.
   - Navigate to root folder on the USB flash drive volume labeled `Install El Capitan`, as shown below.

     [image: Root]
   - In the listview pane, right click, then select "Copy Here", as shown below.

     [image: Root Copy Here]

     Select to copy the `OS X Install ESD\BaseSystem.chunklist` and `OS X Install ESD\BaseSystem.dmg` files in your Downloads folder. Repeat to copy the `InstallAssistant.icns` file in your Downloads folder.
   - In the listview pane, right click on the `InstallAssistant.icns` file, then select "Rename". Change the name to `.VolumeIcon.icns`. When finished, the treeview and listview panes should appear as shown below.

     [image]
   - Navigate to `System\Installation` folder on the USB flash drive labeled `Install El Capitan`, as shown below.

     [image: System\Installation folder]
   - In the listview pane, right click on the `Packages` file, then select "Delete". When prompted, select the `Yes` button in the popup to confirm.
   - In the listview pane, right click, then select "Copy Here", as shown below.

     [image: System\Installation Copy Here]

     Select to copy the `OS X Install ESD\Packages` folder in your Downloads folder. (This may take a while to complete.) When finished, the treeview and listview panes should appear as shown below.

     [image]
   - Close the TransMac window.
8. Use the File Explorer to delete the `OS X Install ESD` folder and `InstallAssistant.icns` file in your Downloads folder. If you wish, you can also delete the downloaded files. When finished, close the File Explorer window, then empty the Recycle Bin.

### References

- [How do I create El Capitan installer on a Catalina (or post-El Capitan) installed Mac for use on USB boot installer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379603/how-do-i-create-el-capitan-installer-on-a-catalina-or-post-el-capitan-installe)
- [TransMac Help](https://www.acutesystems.com/tmac/help/tmhelp.htm)
- [Paragon Hard Disk Manager Version 17 User Manual](https://download.paragon-software.com/doc/Paragon_Hard_Disk_Manager_17.pdf)
- [Apple Disk Image Utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image#Utilities)
- [HFSExplorer](https://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/)
- [DMGExtractor](https://www.catacombae.org/dmgextractor/)
- [dmg2img](http://vu1tur.eu.org/tools/)
- [HFS+ for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/)
- [Tar and Curl Come to Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows)
- [dd for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd)
- [SuperDuper](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html)
- [HOW TO QUICKLY CREATE A MACOS BOOTABLE USB ON WINDOWS 10](https://pureinfotech.com/create-macos-bootable-usb-windows/)

Comment: Nice one! I added this to the canonical list. Hope you don't mind. https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2418/85275

Comment: I'm following this guide to the letter, but when I get to step 6, Paragon Partition Manager doesn't recognize that the USB has a partition on it; it just shows it as "Not formatted." See this screenshot (with my main drive hidden with a black bar): https://i.imgur.com/hIPI76l.png. I tried running through the previous steps again, but no dice. For what it's worth, I'm trying to create a Yosemite installer rather than El Capitan, but the folder structure in the dmg file is the same as this guide so I don't think that would be a problem.

Comment: @user2752467: The steps for Yosemite are different than for El Capitan. This is because Yosemite uses the Apple Partition Map (APM), which is not recognized by the Paragon Partition Manager. El Capitan uses the GUID Partition Map instead, which is recognized by the Paragon Partition Manager. I added a [new question and answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448811/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-yosemite-usb-flash-drive-installer-from) to cover Yosemite.

Comment: Just one addition: Do not unpack the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file to an exFAT formatted partition! I got an error that one file could not be copied! By using an NTFS formatted partition all the files in `InstallMacOSX.dmg` could be unpacked and copied there.

Comment: @Fred-: I posted a new [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/449664#449664) which address your concerns. Basically, the file that could not be copied is actually an alternate data stream. You can ignore this error and proceed with the instructions to create the USB flash drive OS X El Capitan installer. In other words, you do not need an NTFS formatted partition. I also update my first answer so other users will be informed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. The InstallMaxOSX.dmg I downloaded from the Apple store looks different than what you outlined above. The contained InstallMaxOSX.pkg only contains a folder named "." (dot) with a subfolder "Install OS X El Capitan.app". There is no dmg file in the entire package, however, it contains additional filesystem style folders at the top level. It also has over 6 GB, so the dmg file must be somewhere. How can I proceed? Apparently the dmg file is hidden - 7zip says "there's data behind the main data".

Comment: @Razzupaltuff: The instructions given in the above answer do not ask you to download a `InstallMaxOSX.dmg` file from the Apple Store. If this is what you did, then you are not following my answer. Therefore, I have no idea how to advise you.

Comment: It was a typo, obviously. I meant "InstallMacOSX.dmg" as explicitly stated in your instructions (in the table under step 1.).  I did download the correct file (at least going bxy filename) as outlined in your instructions.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff: I believe I can recreate what you have described as ***The contained InstallMaxOSX.pkg only contains a folder named "." (dot) with a subfolder "Install OS X El Capitan.app".*** However, I can not do so by following the instructions that I posted in my answer. Are you sure you followed the instructions as written? Are you sure you choose the __Open Inside *__ action? To get the results you describe, I would have to use the __Open__ action or the __Open Inside__ action.

Comment: I failed to understand the difference between double clicking it or selecting "Open Inside *" from the context menu. That did indeed do the trick. Thank you very much for your effort and your help. :) Btw, when I looked over the guide you have created here I was impressed. You went a long way to write this down, and write it down in such a precise manner. Kudos!

Comment: I am having another problem. With your help, I could create an USB stick as you described, but the Mac computer I am trying to use it on doesn't recognise it as boot device or installation medium. However, the built-in disk manager recognizes the USB stick, but only as a destination device.

Comment: Same issue as @Razzupaltuff - Click your link to download from support.apple.com, can't left click to download for some reason so right click the "El Capitan" link and "Save As", click "Keep", and the dir structure inside the pkg file is nothing like what you show. Also Chrome keeps "Not Responding" whilst the file is downloading, not sure if that's unrelated or not

Comment: Chris: I tried Chrome and was able to download `InstallMaxOSX.dmg`. I did not encounter any issue that I would consider as "Not Responding". I have reread Razzupaltuff's comments and I cannot find where Razzupaltuff was having the same issue.

Comment: If you are referring to the trouble Razzupaltuff had applying the "Open Inside *" action to the `InstallMacOSX.pkg` package file, then can you explain why you cannot resolve this issue the same way Razzupaltuff did? I would also like to point out that nowhere in my answer do I show _"the dir structure inside the pkg file"_.

Comment: Holy s**t, this guide is amazing! I can confirm that the same steps work for macOS Sierra

Answer (score 1):

> **The instructions for using Windows to create an USB flash drive OS X El Capitan installer are given in my first [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/448121#448121). This answer addresses concerns posted by user [Fred -](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/476741/fred) with respect to my first [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/448121#448121).**

My first [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/448121#448121) used the "Copy To…" action to extract the `OS X Install ESD` folder to the users Downloads folder. Here, this Downloads folder is assumed to be in a NTFS formatted volume. However in a now deleted post†, [Fred -](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/476741/fred) stated the following.

> And yes, my Downloads folder is NOT on the system drive and NOT NTFS but ExFAT. One reason for changing the Downloads directory is that my system drive is way too small for all the smaller or bigger downloads. I am convinced, quite a lot of people use non‑default system setups, for instance do not install programs on the system drive but on another partition (as I do whenever possible). ExFAT comes in handy for various reasons, of course not for program installations and things that require NTFS permissions, but for downloads and shared drives this is very good.

*BTW, I believe the "system drive", that [Fred -](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/476741/fred) referred to, is actually called the "Windows partition" in Microsoft documentation.*

In this answer, I used the "Copy To…" action to extract the `OS X Install ESD` folder to a `dma\downloads` folder I created on an exFAT formatted drive `E:`. I received the following popup with a single error message.

[image]

This message is repeated below.

```
Cannot open output file : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : E:\dma\Downloads\OS X Installer ESD\BaseSystem.dmg:com.apple.diskimages.recentcksum
```

By examining the string `BaseSystem.dmg:com.apple.diskimages.recentcksum`, one can determine this string is referring to an [alternate data stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams). Since exFAT does not support alternate data streams, an error message was generated. After further testing, I can state the following.

> **This answer and my original [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/448121#448121) do not require any alternate data streams which can or can not be copied from the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file downloaded from Apple.**

So, if this is the only error message in the popup, then you can ignore the message and proceed with creating the USB flash drive OS X El Capitan installer.

---

†Actually, [Fred -](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/476741/fred) originally posted an answer which was edited by [Fred -](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/476741/fred), then me and finally a moderator. At the time of this posting, the moderator converted the answer to a comment, then deleted the answer.

Comment: @Fred-: I think you still can not post comments. If this is true and you wish to communicate with me, then try editing your deleted answer. I believe I will get a notification of any changes.