# Trying to install El Capitan via Bootable USB on MBP 2009 using Windows 10, not showing up

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, startup, install

I have recently received a 2009 MBP to use with an old video camera. The MBP has no HDD so I formatted an old windows drive to exFAT and have been trying to create a bootable USB for OSX installation, holding down the option key on boot but the bootable USB does not apprear.

I have tried to follow this post but i get stuck at the very beginning:

[How can I use Windows to create an OS X El Capitan USB flash drive installer from the disk image (.dmg) file downloaded from Apple?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/449664#449664)

My InstallMacOSX.dmg (El Capitan file directly from Apple's website for OS's) file does not have this Install ESD file inside of the DMG when using 7Zip, I have tried Mountain Lion, Lion and El Capitan and neither have this file. Maybe this is why it will not appear.

I start my machine up using the option key and the USB bootable does not appear, only the new empty HDD.

This seems to be a common issue with other people who own old MBP of this era, with no original HDD and only a Windows machine.

Comment: By Install ESD file, I assume you are referring to the `InstallESD.dmg` file. I just download the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file for El Capitan from [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683). This file does contain an `InstallESD.dmg` file.

Comment: Do you reach step 3 of [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/448121#448121)? If so, then where in step 3 are you having a problem?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for answering, yes that is where I was getting stuck. This is where I have just realised I have misread your table! I forgot to press " Open Inside* ".

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'll carry on from here and see how far I get. Cheers

Comment: @DavidAnderson All sorted! thank you for the guide! I've tried many in the last 48 hours and yours is the first to work!