# How to reinstalled macOS Sierra from USB Start-up Disk made using TransMac

Tags: macos, startup, install

I have a MacBook Air 7.2 early 2015: i5 2.4GHz, 8Gb DDR3, 121Gb SSD which is completely empty and I want to reinstall macOS on it. I booted my USB key under Macos Sierra from a dmg file with TransMac, but it doesn't appear as an option in Startup Manager.

After checking the key in Ubuntu, I finds that the EFI partition is empty (0 bytes out of 230 mb), which I think is the cause.

The internet resolution offers me as a reinstallation macOS Monterey, and it seems impossible to me with the quality of connection that I have.

How can I get the Sierra installer to boot from a USB drive?

Answer (score 1):

There are ready exists the question [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos) which is similar to your question. However, since you used TransMac, I assume you are trying to create a bootable Sierra installer from a Windows machine. In this case, there is [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/448121#448121) which is for El Captain, but should also work for Sierra. Where necessary you would need to substitute Sierra for El Capitan in the instructions.

Comment: The USB key has indeed been booted under macOS Sierra and I was able to reinstall my Mac! Thanks very much  @David Anderson

Comment: If you feel my answer solved your problem, then please accept the answer. This will put a green check mark next to my answer. Others will then know a solution has been found.