# Unable to re-install macOS on my Mac Mini 2014

Tags: macos, mac-mini, restore

I have a MacMini from 2014.

It has an SSD which I formatted so now it has no OS on it. I tried internet recovery several times but every time I get the error "An Error Occurred While Preparing the Installation". I have tried it again and again after restarting and after formatting again and after using first aid too.

Then I resorted to installing MacOS Sierra using a Bootable USB. I used TransMac to format it and then restore it with the image file of MacOS I downloaded from the site:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

Upon Boot it only showed the Internet recovery option nothing else. It didn't read my USB. I formatted the USB from disk utility with GUID partition scheme and then again chose the restore with image file option and again my MacMini did not read it.

- I don't have any AppleStore in my country so I might not be able to get their help in person to reinstall.
- I only have this one Mac - no other Macs to assist are rentable / borrowable in the immediate future for me

How can I install a macOS on my MacMini again of figure from the logs what the error in question means or understand when an OS install fails?

Comment: If you have an USB Sierra installer flash drive, you can use macOS to create `.dmg` file from this drive. You then can ***just*** use TransMac on a Windows machine to make an USB Sierra installer flash drive from this `.dmg` file. However, you can ***not*** do this from the `.dmg` file you downloaded from Apple by ***just*** using TransMac. You have downloaded a difference kind of `.dmg` file.

Comment: You might want to try my answer to the question [*"How to reinstalled macOS Sierra from USB Start-up Disk made using TransMac*"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453127/how-to-reinstalled-macos-sierra-from-usb-start-up-disk-made-using-transmac/453137#453137).