# Stuck in Kernel Panic 1 after failed OS X install via bootable usb

Tags: usb, startup, install, kernel-panic

I had to do a complete clean reinstall of the OS on a Macbook Pro 5 (late 2009).

Reinstalling the OS through disk recovery didn't work,El capitan is no longer available to download.No backups were made either,trying everything online didn't work,the terminal doesn't help either,single user mode doesn't do anything either,i made a bootable usb,didn't work either.Choose a startup disk? Can't,blank empty nothing shows up. Mind you everything is already deleted from the laptop,every time i would boot up it directly goes to the recovery mode.

Messing with the disk utilities did nothing either. Eventually i managed to get the usb to work somehow,but now i'm stuck in a kernel panic 1 on boot.I can't acces safe mode,recovery mode,or anything else.I've tried resetting the pram,that didn't do anything either.I'm at a loss of words. The error looks like any other panic code,but i've noticed one thing in it "Mac OS Version:Not Yet Set". Is it possible that i've somehow managed to delete EVERYTHING?

My USB no longer shows up when i press the button to show what i want to boot from.I do not have another mac available,only a windows pc,and i'm really trying to get this thing to work but it won't budge no matter what.Please help.

Comment: What does the 5 stand for in MacBook Pro 5? El Capitan is available to download. You can use Windows to make bootable USB installers.

Comment: Apple MacBook Pro 15-Inch "Core 2 Duo" is the name of the laptop,on the kernel screen it says MacBook Pro 5.El Capitan is NOT available for download.I AM using windows to make a bootable usb. I am currently stuck in KERNEL PANIC after using a bootable usb. How do i get out of KERNEL PANIC? My usb used to show up in the bootable devices,that is no longer.

Comment: An official link to download El Capitan is available at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

Comment: Sob: I do not know what procedure you are using to make a bootable USB. I would recommend using the procedure given as the accepted answer to the question [How can I use Windows to create an OS X El Capitan USB flash drive installer from the disk image (.dmg) file downloaded from Apple?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro).

Comment: Sob: I do not know how much experience you have with installing OS X. After booting from the USB installer, you should use the Disk Utility to erase the internal drive before attempting to install OS X on the internal drive. When erasing choose `Macintosh HD` for Name, `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` for the format and `GUID Partition Map` as the Scheme.

Comment: Now that link worked, thank you. I was able to get my mac up and running.