# Completely disconnect Apple computer from user ID

Tags: macos, install, apple-id

I have been given an older Apple computer (the kind where everything is in the screen case), but I cannot use it, because it is linked to the Apple ID of the previous owner, who I have no means of reaching anymore.

I have already tried to reinstall OS X (El Capitan) from USB stick (which I prepared on a Windows PC following instructions given in another thread here), but when that was done, I ended up at the login screen requiring me to enter the previous owner's credentials.

How do I get rid of that, so that I can link that computer to another Apple ID.

Comment: *Actually* Older Macs were not difficult to repurpose at all. When you boot into the installer, use disk utility to delete all the existing partitions and create a new one. The installer will do what it needs to do and then install a fresh copy of OSX. This is all assuming that it was not enrolled in an MDM, which has security that would prevent making this iMac yours.

Comment: Ask the person who gave it to you.

Comment: That person is not reachable anymore.

Comment: @SteveChambers I actually deleted everything from the HD. However, the Mac doesn't seem to recognise my OS X installation USB stick. It gets detected by the disk manager, but not offered as an installation source or handled as a boot device.

Comment: Do an internet search for "create bootable macOS install media" there is a different macOS command for each version of macOS that will create bootable media to install each version of macOS. Unless you have already done this that is why your USB stick is not bootable.

Comment: I only have Windows PCs. I followed this guide to create a bootable USB stick: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro

Comment: FYI, Macs where everything is in the screen are called iMac (unless it's one of the early models from the 80's, which are just Macintosh, but none of those can run Mac OS X).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your iMac is a boat anchor.

The way Apple security works is that your computer is tied to your Apple ID. this is a double edged sword:  it supposedly disincentives thefts, but if you purchased a pre-owned unit that hasn’t been dissociated from the previous owner, it’s only good for parts.

Now, this applies to Mac computers with the [T2 security chip](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204921).  If you didn’t *erase* the drive before installing macOS, then you’ll see the previous users login.

Comment: If the person you got the Mac from has not removed it from their AppleID account you may have issues with it, but if you have a legit bill of sale Apple support may be able to help with that.

Comment: There's really no way to factory reset it?

Comment: It’s designed to prevent stolen devices from being usable.  There is no way to reset it.