# How do I install El Capitan to an erased Mac that can’t "Reinstall OS X"

Tags: macos, hard-drive, install, apple-id, recovery

I have an old Mac (El Capitan) that has all the data erased, and I want to reinstall the OS, but I cant because "Reinstall OS X" doesnt work and just shows "this item is temporarily unavailable" whenever I enter Apple ID.
changing the date in terminal doesnt work either.
I dont have another mac where I can make a bootable USB, I can't access another Apple ID, and I dont have Internet Recovery Mode.
I've tried everything,

(my Mac is a 2009 model, I tried installing through "Reinstall OS X" but it showed "this item is temporarily unavailable", I tried changing the time to an earlier date in Terminal but that didn't work, I can't access Internet Recovery Mode, and I don't have another Mac where I can create a bootable USB drive.)

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399/119271 ?

Comment: As a last resort, you can use a [machine running Windows to create a bootable USB El Capitan installer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-or-macos-sierra-usb-flash-dri/448121#448121). Do you have access to a Windows machine?

Comment: yeah i do.can i create a bootable usb with a windows?

Comment: Is there some reason you can not goto https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683 on your Mac and download El Capitan? Once downloaded, you can create the Install OS X El Capitan application. Finally, use the instructions at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372 to create a USB bootable El Capitan installer.

Comment: my mac is bricked and stuck in recovery mode, so i cant do anything

Comment: Have to tried create a USB bootable El Capitan installer using a Window machine? The instructions a given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-or-macos-sierra-usb-flash-dri/448121#448121).

Comment: ill try that, thanks