# Issues trying to use TransMac to create bootable USB from Windows 10

Tags: macos, windows, usb, install, dmg

I'm trying to follow the steps in this post:
[How can I use Windows to create an OS X El Capitan or macOS Sierra USB flash drive installer from the disk image (.dmg) file downloaded from Apple?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-or-macos-sierra-usb-flash-drive)
Which was answered by David Anderson. I'm on step 7 and cannot 'copy here' any files from my downloads folder and also cannot rename or delete any files from within the USB drive in TransMac.
I have been trying to make this bootable USB for days now following different guides and this seems like the best and most detailed one but I'm just stuck on this bit because I can't get it to work.

Comment: The current rules are that new users have to post new questions when prohibited from posting comments. You do not have to state this in your question, so I edited and removed this.

Comment: I tested my posted answer and could not reproduce the copy, rename or delete issues post in your question. More details may be helpful. For example, I do not even know if you are trying to create a bootable USB installer for El Capitan or Sierra.