# Install Mac EL Capitan without Apple check

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mac-appstore, internet

is there a way to install el capitan without internet and apple check?
I have tried various ways, but unfortunately none of them work:
download el capitan from apple: http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-41424-20191024-218af9ec-cf50-4516-9011-228c78eda3d2/InstallMacOSX.dmg
usb boot stick created: with windows, TransMac tool
after restart:
alt-cmd-p-r
cmd-s
change date date:0711141516
exit
format disc
start install

Unfortunately it always appears that an internet connection is required and when i do this i get the message that it does not work

Comment: See https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-fix-the-recovery-server-could-not-be-contacted-error-high-sierra-recovery-is-still-online-but-broken/ - i cannot test whether this method might also work for El Capitan.

Comment: What model Mac are you attempting to install to, and is there a good reason why you can't connect it to the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

From your abbreviated instructions, I think you did the following.

1. Downloaded `InstallMacOSX.dmg` to a Windows machine.
2. You used Transmac to transfer `InstallMacOSX.dmg` to a USB flash drive. Note that this flash drive would not be bootable. If you though so, you would be wrong. The procedure to create a bootable USB flash drive El Capitan installer is more complicated than just using Transmac. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-or-macos-sierra-usb-flash-dri/448121#448121).
3. Changed the date on the Mac. I assume you thought an earlier date is needed to complete the install. I believe Apple has updated the current `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file download so changing the date should not be unnecessary.